# phonegap camera plugin insert memory card to use camera

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

**Cordova version 3.6.3-0.2.13**

I'm playing around with the code in
Apache Cordova API Cookbook
the code is like:

```
//Defines the button label for alert dialogs
      var btnText = "Continue";

      function onBodyLoad() {
        //Let the user know we've launched
        alert("onBodyLoad");
        //Set the Cordova deviceready event listener, so we'll know
        //when Cordova is ready
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      }

      function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("Entering onDeviceReady");
        //Let the user know that the deviceReady event has fired        
        navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is ready", null, "Device Ready", btnText);
        console.log("Leaving onDeviceReady");
      }

      function takePhoto() {
        console.log("Entering takePhoto");
        navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError);
        console.log("Entering takePhoto");
      }

      function cameraSuccess(imageURL) {
        console.log("Entering cameraSuccess");
        navigator.notification.alert(imageURL, null, "Photo Results", btnText);
        console.log("Leaving cameraSuccess");
      }

      function cameraError(errObj) {
        console.log("Entering cameraError");
        console.error(JSON.stringify(errObj));
        navigator.notification.alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(errObj), null, "Camera Error", btnText);
        console.log("Leaving cameraError");
      }
```

but when I run

**cordova -d run android**

and the app is installed in my device (Samsung Ace android 2.3)

I get the message

*Insert memory card to use camera*

of course if I use the camera on its own
it works and store the pic in my gallery

so I'm wondering what is the problem ?

**UPDATE**

if I unplug the usb cable it works !

Answer (score 0):

Is the Camera.DestinationType messed up.

[cordova.camera](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.camera) says

> To avoid common memory problems, set Camera.destinationType to FILE_URI rather than DATA_URL

Comment: the error is 'Insert memory card to use camera' both with FILE_URI and DATA_URL. The strange thing is if I unplug the usb cable it works !